# Change formatting in \cref

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

Sorry if this question is a duplicate but I couldn't find a solution anywhere. I want to define a command with two arguments which does the following

```
\newcommand{ThecommandIwant}[2]{#1.\cref{#2}}
```

Now this doesn't produce what I want. For example it would produce #1.theorem/proposition the number corresponding to #2. Instead I want something that produces theorem/proposition #1.the number corresponding to #2.

Edit: #2 represents the label of the referred item (say a theorem). #1 will be something that I want to add eventually between "theorem" and the referred number. For example if `\cref{#2}` produces "theorem 1.2" I want my command to produce "theorem #1.1.2".

Here is an example

```
\usepackage{amsmath,cleveref}
%here I define my command called "ThecommandIwant"
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{a}
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}\label{b}
\end{theorem}
\ThecommandIwant{Train}{a} %prints theorem Train.1
\ThecommandIwant{Plane}{b} %prints theorem Plane.2
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The line of code (although) wrong) does not reveal what you really want to achieve. Please provide a compilable document. Perhaps it should be `\newcommand{\ThecommandIwant}[2]{\cref{#1}.\ref{#2}}`  This depends on what `#1` and `#2` should represent, however? Apparently those are label names, but why two of them?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer This wouldn't work. #2 represents the label of the referred item (say a theorem). #1 will be something that I want to add eventually between "theorem" and the referred number. For example if cref{#2} produces "theorem 1.2" I want my command to produce "theorem #1.1.2"

Comment: Please provide the compilable document with a setup that shows what you want to achieve. At the moment, it is not clear

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I added a concrete example. I hope this clarifies my question.

Comment: That's  not compilable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

I am not sure that this is possible with `\crefformat` or `\creflabelformat` from `cleveref` without heavy tricks at all, but I provide a solution with `crossreftools`, that extracts the information stored by `cleveref` to the `.aux` file and reconstructs the output according to the required output.

The underlying counter is auto-detected (!!!!) by `\crtcrefcounter` and handed over to `\crtcrefname` that prints the cross reference name according to the `\crefname` etc. settings.

The provided solution below is aware of linking if `hyperref` is used as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{crossreftools}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ThecommandIwant}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{r@#2}{}{%
    \if@crt@hyperrefloaded
    \hyperlink{\crtrefanchor{#2}}{\crtcrefname{\crtcrefcounter{#2}} #1.\crtcrefnumber{#2}}%
    \else
    \crtcrefname{\crtcrefcounter{#2}} #1.\crtcrefnumber{#2}%
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{a}
\end{theorem}

\clearpage
\begin{theorem}\label{b}
\end{theorem}

\clearpage
\ThecommandIwant{Train}{a} %prints theorem Train.1
\ThecommandIwant{Plane}{b} %prints theorem Plane.2

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `cleveref` package defines a `\namecref` and a `\labelcref` commands...

Comment: @HugoRaguet: Yes, but they are not expandable...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: actually my poor knowledge of TeX is reached already. I do not know what expandable mean. But I can assure you that my answer below works well (now), at least on simple instances.

Answer (score 3):

With `cleveref`, define a suitable `\crefformat`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\let\omarlabel\@gobble
\makeatother
\newcommand{\foo}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\omarlabel{#1}%
  \cref{#2}%
  \endgroup
}
\crefdefaultlabelformat{#2\omarlabel.#1#3}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}\label{0}

\begin{theorem}\label{a}
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\label{b}
\end{theorem}

\foo{Whatever}{0}

\foo{Train}{a} %prints theorem Train.1

\foo{Plane}{b} %prints theorem Plane.2

\cref{0}

\cref{a}

\cref{b}

\end{document}
```

The `\omarlabel` command, by default, gobbles the period, but `\foo` redefines it to be the stated additional label.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately your command always prints theorem (it doesn't read the "theorem" from cref package)

Comment: @omar I can answer what you ask, not what you don't. However, I polished my crystal ball…

Comment: Thanks. Your crystal ball is quite elegant. It does exactly what I want.

Comment: @omar    

Answer (score 3):

I find the answers of Christian Hupfer and egreg a bit complicated; the first needs an additional package, the second redefines all the labels, which is annoying.
I propose simply

```
\newcommand*{\omaref}[2]{\namecref{#2}~#1.\labelcref{#2}}
```

or for better interaction with `hyperref`

```
\newcommand*{\omaref}[2]{%
    \hyperref[#2]{\namecref{#2}~#1.\labelcref*{#2}}
}
```

Comment: Did you try this? I get a warning about an undefined reference `*`, which is most likely from `\namecref*`, which is does not exist. `\namecref*{#2}` will try to use `\namecref{*}` basically -- this is not what is requested

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: thank you, I accidentally let two typos in my answer. As you have pointed out the starred form of `\namecref` does not exist. I corrected it and it now works well.